# PHP/Apache refuses to be given privileges to create a file

Tags: php, linux, apache, unix

I have a PHP script that's part of a larger website that I'm writing. I have a little apache server running on my laptop so I can test out different parts of the website as I build them.

As part of the website, I would like the user to pick from a series of files that I have on the server. When they select the files and hit 'download', a PHP script receives instructions on what files are to be download, zips up the files in a .zip archive, and pushes them to the browser for download.

```
<?php   
    $files = $_POST['files'];
    $zipname = 'ncd_data.zip';

    $zip = new ZipArchive;
    $zip->open($zipname, ZipArchive::CREATE)

    foreach ($files as $file) {
        $zip->addFile($file);
    }
    $zip->close();    

    if (file_exists($zip)) {
        header('Content-Type: application/zip');
        header('Content-Disposition: attachment; filename=ncd_data.zip');
        header('Content-Length: ' . filesize($zip));
        readfile($zip);
        exit;
    }
?>
```

Upon testing, it became apparent that the script wasn't able to create a .zip file. Running `exec('whoami')` in the php script showed that the script was being run under the user `apache`, I proceeded to give apache the permissions it needed to create the file.

Through using `chmod` and `chown`, apache now has 755 permissions for everything within the 'html' folder the code for the website is in (as well as owns everything in and including the `html` folder):

```
[root@callisto var]# ls -l /var/www/html/
total 104
-rwxrwxr-x+ 1 apache root   420 Mar 20 16:54 about.php
-rwxrwxr-x+ 1 apache root   346 Mar 20 15:34 about.php~
drwxrwxr-x+ 2 apache root  4096 Mar 20 15:34 css
-rwxrwxr-x+ 1 apache root  1341 Mar 20 16:54 download.php
-rwxrwxr-x+ 1 apache root  1331 Mar 20 15:34 download.php~
-rwxrwxr-x+ 1 apache root   349 Mar 20 16:54 index.php
-rwxrwxr-x+ 1 apache root   346 Mar 20 15:34 index.php~
drwxrwxr-x+ 2 apache root  4096 Mar 20 15:34 js
drwxrwxr-x+ 2 apache root 12288 Mar 20 15:34 nucleidata
drwxrwxr-x+ 2 apache root  4096 Mar 20 15:58 php
-rwxrwxr-x+ 1 apache root  1332 Mar 20 16:54 plot.php
-rwxrwxr-x+ 1 apache root  1254 Mar 20 15:34 plot.php~
```

As well as `rwx` permissions all the way up to `/var/` using `setfacl`. Still, no dice: I'm gettting a 'permission denied' error when running a `mkdir` command within the php script despite all of this. I know that giving the `html` folder full 777 permissions is a Bad Idea, but I'm stumped as to what else I need to do to give PHP the permissions it needs to create and write to files.

My setup is a Fedora 20 laptop, PHP and Apache are their latest versions, respectively (5.5.10 and 2.4.7). Thanks in advance.

Comment: It doesn't look like you need to keep the zip file around, so you might be better off just creating it in a temporary directory and deleting it at the end

Comment: I'm probably going to end up doing that, but that's not the problem - the zip file can't be created in the first place.

Comment: what is the rights/owner/group of ls -ld /var/www/html/ ?

Comment: I'm pretty sure you need to write the zip file to a 777 directory.  I'd make a special directory for that, and have cron run a php every minute (or whatever) to unlink all files over 10 minutes old.

Comment: progysm ouput of your command is `drwxrwxr-x+ 6 apache root 4096 Mar 20 15:38 /var/www/html/`. BarryDevSF, The problem is that the script can't *create* a .zip file in the first place, I'm not quite clear as to how your suggestion would fix that.